# SAP webi 4.3 get first and last date of a selected month & year

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, business-objects, webi

I have a report that’s connected to oracle database. This report takes 2 prompts

1. Month (in number)
2. Year

Is there a way that I can get the first date and last date of the selected month & year ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxCmW.png)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to concatenate month and year and apply that (`mmyyyy`) format model to `to_date` function - that returns the first date in that month. Additionally, apply `last_day` function to that and you'll get (as its name says) last date.

This is a SQL*Plus example:

```
SQL> select          to_date(lpad(&&p_month, 2, '0') || &&p_year, 'mmyyyy')  first_date,
  2         last_day(to_date(lpad(&&p_month, 2, '0') || &&p_year, 'mmyyyy')) last_date
  3  from dual;
Enter value for p_month: 4
Enter value for p_year: 2022

FIRST_DATE          LAST_DATE
------------------- -------------------
01.04.2022 00:00:00 30.04.2022 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Depending on the way you're passing values to such a query, you might need to use e.g. bind variables:

```
select          to_date(lpad(:p_month, 2, '0') || :p_year, 'mmyyyy')  first_date,
       last_day(to_date(lpad(:p_month, 2, '0') || :p_year, 'mmyyyy')) last_date
from dual;
```

or something similar (I don't know SAP Webi), but - that's the general idea.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately it doesn’t work in webi

Comment: Unfortunately :( I hope someone else will be able to assist.